# Compressing multiple files from S3 using WebFlux on the fly

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux

I need to create a zip file on the fly from a set of objects in S3 and return it as a `Flux<ByteBuffer>` (or equivalent). The zip can be large (100's of MB's, possibly several GB's, so downloading all the objects to either RAM or disk is not an option)

The current implementation, while complicated (using `PipedInputStream`/`PipedOutputStream`), works on smaller files but crashes on larger inputs (10's of input files for a total of ~ 1 GB raw size)

Is there any implementation of a fully streamed zip library using WebFlux? I can switch to tar/gzip if a more idiomatic implementation than `ZipOutputStream` exists for tgz

TIA :)

Edit: stack trace

```
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Assembly trace from producer [reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap] :
    reactor.core.publisher.Mono.flatMap
    org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.annotation.ResponseEntityResultHandler.handleResult(ResponseEntityResultHandler.java:132)
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    *____________Mono.flatMap ⇢ at org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.annotation.ResponseEntityResultHandler.handleResult(ResponseEntityResultHandler.java:132)
    |_             checkpoint ⇢ Exception handler com.refinitiv.itop.controller.advice.GlobalExceptionHandler#handleNotFoundException(RuntimeException), error="The downloading file='batch-conversion/EES_PDFTRON/results/5f0cd366-5fed-42ab-934a-cafca73f7423/21927289.pdf.json' was failed, message: Unable to execute HTTP request: Acquire operation took longer than the configured maximum time. This indicates that a request cannot get a connection from the pool within the specified maximum time. This can be due to high request rate.
Consider taking any of the following actions to mitigate the issue: increase max connections, increase acquire timeout, or slowing the request rate.
Increasing the max connections can increase client throughput (unless the network interface is already fully utilized), but can eventually start to hit operation system limitations on the number of file descriptors used by the process. If you already are fully utilizing your network interface or cannot further increase your connection count, increasing the acquire timeout gives extra time for requests to acquire a connection before timing out. If the connections doesn't free up, the subsequent requests will still timeout.
If the above mechanisms are not able to fix the issue, try smoothing out your requests so that large traffic bursts cannot overload the client, being more efficient with the number of times you need to call AWS, or by increasing the number of hosts sending requests." [DispatcherHandler]
    *____________Mono.flatMap ⇢ at org.springframework.web.reactive.DispatcherHandler.lambda$handleResult$5(DispatcherHandler.java:182)
    *______Mono.onErrorResume ⇢ at org.springframework.web.reactive.DispatcherHandler.handleResult(DispatcherHandler.java:181)
    |_                        ⇢ at org.springframework.web.reactive.DispatcherHandler.lambda$handle$2(DispatcherHandler.java:154)
    *____________Mono.flatMap ⇢ at org.springframework.web.reactive.DispatcherHandler.handle(DispatcherHandler.java:154)
    |_                        ⇢ at org.springframework.web.server.handler.DefaultWebFilterChain.lambda$filter$0(DefaultWebFilterChain.java:120)
    *______________Mono.defer ⇢ at org.springframework.web.server.handler.DefaultWebFilterChain.filter(DefaultWebFilterChain.java:119)
    |_                        ⇢ at com.refinitiv.itop.web.IndexFilter.filter(IndexFilter.java:23)
    |_             checkpoint ⇢ com.refinitiv.itop.web.IndexFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_                        ⇢ at org.springframework.web.server.handler.DefaultWebFilterChain.lambda$filter$0(DefaultWebFilterChain.java:120)
    *______________Mono.defer ⇢ at org.springframework.web.server.handler.DefaultWebFilterChain.filter(DefaultWebFilterChain.java:119)
    |_          Mono.doOnEach ⇢ at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.reactive.server.MetricsWebFilter.filter(MetricsWebFilter.java:87)
    |_        Mono.doOnCancel ⇢ at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.reactive.server.MetricsWebFilter.filter(MetricsWebFilter.java:88)
    *__Mono.transformDeferred ⇢ at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.reactive.server.MetricsWebFilter.filter(MetricsWebFilter.java:82)
    |_             checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.reactive.server.MetricsWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_                        ⇢ at org.springframework.web.server.handler.DefaultWebFilterChain.lambda$filter$0(DefaultWebFilterChain.java:120)
    *______________Mono.defer ⇢ at org.springframework.web.server.handler.DefaultWebFilterChain.filter(DefaultWebFilterChain.java:119)
    |_                        ⇢ at org.springframework.web.server.handler.FilteringWebHandler.handle(FilteringWebHandler.java:59)
    |_                        ⇢ at org.springframework.web.server.handler.WebHandlerDecorator.handle(WebHandlerDecorator.java:56)
    |_     Mono.onErrorResume ⇢ at org.springframework.web.server.handler.ExceptionHandlingWebHandler.handle(ExceptionHandlingWebHandler.java:77)
    |_     Mono.onErrorResume ⇢ at org.springframework.web.server.handler.ExceptionHandlingWebHandler.handle(ExceptionHandlingWebHandler.java:77)
    |_     Mono.onErrorResume ⇢ at org.springframework.web.server.handler.ExceptionHandlingWebHandler.handle(ExceptionHandlingWebHandler.java:77)
    |_       Mono.doOnSuccess ⇢ at org.springframework.web.server.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter.handle(HttpWebHandlerAdapter.java:249)
    |_     Mono.onErrorResume ⇢ at org.springframework.web.server.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter.handle(HttpWebHandlerAdapter.java:250)
    *______________Mono.error ⇢ at org.springframework.web.server.handler.ExceptionHandlingWebHandler$CheckpointInsertingHandler.handle(ExceptionHandlingWebHandler.java:98)
    |_             checkpoint ⇢ HTTP GET "/api/v1/batch-conversion/download?batchId=5f0cd366-5fed-42ab-934a-cafca73f7423&includeResults=true&includeErrors=false" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
    |_                        ⇢ at org.springframework.web.server.handler.ExceptionHandlingWebHandler.lambda$handle$0(ExceptionHandlingWebHandler.java:77)
    *______________Mono.error ⇢ at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.reactive.error.AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler.handle(AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler.java:306)
    |_                        ⇢ at org.springframework.web.server.handler.ExceptionHandlingWebHandler.lambda$handle$0(ExceptionHandlingWebHandler.java:77)
    *______________Mono.error ⇢ at org.springframework.web.server.handler.ResponseStatusExceptionHandler.handle(ResponseStatusExceptionHandler.java:68)
    |_                        ⇢ at org.springframework.web.server.handler.ExceptionHandlingWebHandler.lambda$handle$0(ExceptionHandlingWebHandler.java:77)
    *______________Mono.error ⇢ at org.springframework.web.server.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter.handleUnresolvedError(HttpWebHandlerAdapter.java:310)
    |_                        ⇢ at org.springframework.web.server.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter.lambda$handle$3(HttpWebHandlerAdapter.java:250)
    *_______________Mono.then ⇢ at org.springframework.web.server.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter.handle(HttpWebHandlerAdapter.java:251)
    |_                        ⇢ at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.WebServerManager$DelayedInitializationHttpHandler.handle(WebServerManager.java:98)
    |_         Mono.doOnError ⇢ at org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ReactorHttpHandlerAdapter.apply(ReactorHttpHandlerAdapter.java:66)
    |_       Mono.doOnSuccess ⇢ at org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ReactorHttpHandlerAdapter.apply(ReactorHttpHandlerAdapter.java:67)
    |_        Mono.fromDirect ⇢ at reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServer$HttpServerHandle.lambda$onStateChange$0(HttpServer.java:962)
    *____Mono.deferContextual ⇢ at reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServer$HttpServerHandle.onStateChange(HttpServer.java:960)
Original Stack Trace:
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.annotation.AbstractMessageWriterResultHandler.writeBody(AbstractMessageWriterResultHandler.java:183)
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.annotation.ResponseEntityResultHandler.lambda$handleResult$1(ResponseEntityResultHandler.java:168)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap.trySubscribeScalarMap(FluxFlatMap.java:152)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.subscribeOrReturn(MonoFlatMap.java:53)
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:57)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:157)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1816)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:151)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1816)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip$ZipCoordinator.signal(MonoZip.java:251)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip$ZipInner.onNext(MonoZip.java:336)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2398)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip$ZipInner.onSubscribe(MonoZip.java:325)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:55)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4400)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip.subscribe(MonoZip.java:128)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4400)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:103)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onError(MonoPeekTerminal.java:258)
        at org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ChannelSendOperator$WriteCompletionBarrier.onError(ChannelSendOperator.java:414)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreElements$IgnoreElementsSubscriber.onError(MonoIgnoreElements.java:84)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatArray$ConcatArraySubscriber.onError(FluxConcatArray.java:207)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.onError(MonoIgnoreThen.java:278)
        at reactor.netty.channel.MonoSendMany$SendManyInner.run(MonoSendMany.java:351)
        at reactor.netty.channel.MonoSendMany$SendManyInner.trySchedule(MonoSendMany.java:422)
        at reactor.netty.channel.MonoSendMany$SendManyInner.trySuccess(MonoSendMany.java:586)
        at reactor.netty.channel.MonoSendMany$SendManyInner.trySuccess(MonoSendMany.java:117)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.PromiseCombiner.tryPromise(PromiseCombiner.java:170)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.PromiseCombiner.access$600(PromiseCombiner.java:35)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.PromiseCombiner$1.operationComplete0(PromiseCombiner.java:62)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.PromiseCombiner$1.operationComplete(PromiseCombiner.java:44)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:578)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:552)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:491)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:616)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setSuccess0(DefaultPromise.java:605)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.trySuccess(DefaultPromise.java:104)
        at io.netty.util.internal.PromiseNotificationUtil.trySuccess(PromiseNotificationUtil.java:48)
        at io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundBuffer.safeSuccess(ChannelOutboundBuffer.java:717)
        at io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundBuffer.remove(ChannelOutboundBuffer.java:272)
        at io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundBuffer.removeBytes(ChannelOutboundBuffer.java:352)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel.writeBytesMultiple(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:305)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel.doWriteMultiple(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:510)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel.doWrite(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:422)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush0(AbstractChannel.java:931)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe.epollOutReady(AbstractEpollChannel.java:570)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:470)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:378)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
"}
```

Comment: What's an error, and what does input from s3 looks like? is it already some flux-ex or what?

Comment: @gdomo the S3 objects are fetched using a Flux. Will add full stack trace to question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: Fixed!

The answer was 2-pronged:

1. Limit all `flatMap`s in the relevant code to `parallelism = 1` & `prefetch = 1` to limit the amount of open S3 handles
2. Break the `Flux` into 2 `Flux`es:

   1. S3 reader - `.subscribe()` on a different `Thread`; writes to a `ZipOutputStream` wrapping a `PipedOutputStream`
   2. Web response - created on the main thread; reads from the `PipedInputStream`

```
PipedInputStream pis = new PipedInputStream(streamBufferSize);
PipedOutputStream pos = new PipedOutputStream(pis);
ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(pos);

Flux<ByteBuffer> resultFlux = Flux.create(sink -> {
    while (true) {
        var bytes = new byte[streamBufferSize];
        try {
            int read = pis.read(bytes);
            if (read > 0) {
                sink.next(ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes, 0, read));
            } else {
                sink.complete();
                break;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("zip output stream crashed for {}", batchId, e);
            sink.error(e);
            break;
        }
    }
});

var reader = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        s3DownloadsFlux.map(chunk -> {
            //snipped: minutiae of actually writing to the `ZipOutputStream` and error handling
          
            return new Object(); //doesn't matter what is returned
        }).subscribe();
    }
};

new Thread(reader).start();

return resultFlux;
```